# API Яндекс.Коннект - Добавление сотрудника (ошибка)

Tags: curl, яндекс-коннект

Хочу добавить сотрудника в яндекс коннект.
Отправляю запрос-образец из документации, подставив свой токен:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"department_id": 1, "password": "test100500", "nickname": "vasily", "name": {"first": "Василий", "last": "Петров"}}' -H "Authorization: OAuth _здесь_кой_токен_" 'https://api.directory.yandex.net/v6/users/'
```

Получаю ошибку:

> This operation requires one of scopes: directory:write_users,
>   directory:manage_yamb_bots

Разрешения:

> Яндекс.Ямб
>   - Чтение и отправка сообщений в Ямбе API Яндекс.Паспорта
>
> - Доступ к логину, имени и фамилии, полу
> - Доступ к адресу электронной почты
> - Доступ к дате рождения
> - Доступ к портрету пользователя Яндекс.Почтовый офис
>     Получение данных Яндекс.Почта
>
> Отправка писем через Яндекс.Почту по протоколу SMTP
>
> - Доступ на чтение писем в почтовом ящике
>
> Чтение и удаление писем в почтовом ящике Яндекс.Почта для доменов
>
> - Чтение списка доменов и ящиков, подключение доменов, создание и
>     удаление ящиков в Яндекс.Почте для домена